# returning a value from a two arrays and a count integer C language

Tags: c, arrays, parameters

```
int main()
{
    double dUnitPriceM[]={19.99, 50.50, 2.10};
    long lOrderQuantityM[] = {10, 2, 4};
    int iItemCount = 3;
    double dTotalCost;
    dTotalCost = calculateTotalCost(dUnitPriceM, lOrderQuantityM, iItemCount);
    printf("Total cost is %10.2lf\n", dTotalCost);
}
// code for calculateTotalCost function ??
double calculateTotalCost(double dUnitPriceM[], long lQuantityM[], 
int iItemCount)
{
}
```

I am a beginner for coding C language and I am having trouble understanding how to use Arrays. I came up with the logic of creating a pseudocode but I cant code it. 
All I know is that I have to start from the value of i =1; as i <= Item count, i++.

then assign i the result of the UnitPriceM[0] * QuantityM[0], increment them to the next array until it has reached its last value. Then sum the total of all the i's for example if i1= 100 + i2 = 120 + i3 =45 return them as the total cost.

Comment: arrays in `c` are indexed beginning at 0 and stretching to their length-1. So you should loop from `i=0; i<itemCount;`. For example, `int myArray[3];` has valid indices `myArray[0]`, `myArray[1]`, and `myArray[2]` ... `myArray[3]` accesses beyond the end of the array and invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is the basic logic of looping through all and doing the operation required.

```
double calculateTotalCost(double dUnitPriceM[], long lQuantityM[], 
int iItemCount)
{
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<iItemCount;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+dUnitPriceM[i]*lQuantityM[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    double calculateTotalCost(double unitPrice[], long quantity[],int itemCount){
       int i;
       double totalCost=0.0;

       for(i=0;i<itemCount;i++){
           totalCost +=unitPrice[i] * quantity[i];
        }
        return totalCost;

    }
    void main() {
        int i;
        double dUnitPriceM[]={19.99, 50.50, 2.10};
        long lOrderQuantityM[] = {10, 2, 4};
        int iItemCount = 3;
        double totalCost =0.0;
        totalCost= calculateTotalCost(dUnitPriceM, lOrderQuantityM, iItemCount);
         printf("Total cost is %f ", totalCost);
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.